# ComboBox strategies to function

Tags: methods, combobox, redundancy

I have four combo box everything does the same as follows:

```
Select Case combobox1.selectedItem
case 0 
str=str & "' AND"
case 1
str= str & "'"
end case

select case combobox2.selected item
 case 0 
str=str & "' AND"
case 1
str= str & "'"
end case
```

Similarly the other two comboboxes have the same body

I want to replace this code block by a method call and implement the select clause body in a method body and call it when required.

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method that takes the input as combobox selected index i.e an integer
now in the method write as follows:

```
method1(int x)
{
Select Case x 
case 0 
str=str & "' AND"
case 1
str= str & "'"
end case
}
```

Call `method1` where required.